# Accessing json_decode array values from php

Tags: arrays, json, localization

I’m trying to setup simple localization on a flat file MVC (Slim & Twig) using Json for each virtual page data.
I fetch (with PHP json-decode function set to true) an external json formated data file and I have problems finding the simplest way to access the json-decoded array so it is straightforward in the code to access the externalized text.

I used to have an xml flat file with different language version and I'm moving to JSON formatted data files. I found a way to access the array but I was looking for a simpler way of setting both JSON structure and accessing the data via the returned array provided by json_decode. 
Here is my Json file:

```
{
"title": [
  { "fr" : "VERSION FRANCAISE FR" },
  { "en" : "English IN ENGLISH"  },
  { "es": “Spanish Version” }
],
"description":[
  { "fr"  :"FR DESCRIPTION" },
  { "en"  :"ENGlish DESCRIPTION"  },
  { "es"  :"ES DESCRIPTION" }
],
"keywords":[
  { "fr"  :"mot clés, séparés par virgules, mots clés" },
  { "en"  :"keywords, ENGlish keywords"  },
  { "es"  :"en espagnol" }
]
}
```

Here is the code I use to access the data:

```
$file =“meta.json”;
$str = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$file)
$meta = json_decode($str, true);
```

// access $meta array

```
// this works
echo $meta['title'][0]['fr'];
echo $meta['title'][1]['en'];
echo $meta['title'][2]['es'];

// this doesn’t
echo $meta['title']['fr'];
echo $meta['title']['en'];
echo $meta['title']['es'];
```

Maybe I can have the language at the top of the array and title, description as follows

```
  {
    "fr": [
      { "title" : "VERSION French" },
      { "description" : "French"  },
      { "keywords": "french" }
    ],
    "en":[
      { "title" : "VERSION EN" },
      { "description" : "ENGlish IN ENGLISH"  },
      { "keywords": "English" }
    ],
    "es":[
      { "title" : "Spanish version" },
      { "description" : "Description ES"  },
      { "keywords": "keywords in ES" }
    ]
    }
```

But the same problems arrises I would have to write
echo $meta['fr'][0]['title'];
to get to the title in french

So the question is there a way to turn things round so I can use a simple meaningful syntax like  $meta['fr']['title']; and not having to relate to a numerical value index.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your numeric arrays seem redundant. If your keys are unique then use them as keys like in your first example, except without wrapping the objects in `[]` -

```
{
  "fr": {
    "title" : "VERSION French",
    "description" : "French"
    "keywords": "french"
  }
},
```

Then you can access them like you suggest, with: `$meta['fr']['title']`

Comment: Thank you for that, I thought the square brackets were mandatory! Works like a charm and simple enough for my case to keep on working! Cheers